# Chromium and Dart: "An error occurred loading file"

Tags: apache, dart, phpstorm, chromium

I'm trying to run some Dart templates from [Stagehand](https://github.com/google/stagehand/tree/master/templates). The 'ubersimplewebapp' app works. There's almost nothing to it. I've tried a couple of others and they don't. I'm currently trying to get 'webapp' to work. In install using PHPStorm and there are no errors. When I run it in the Chromium browser, I get the following console errors:

```
GET http://dartorium.loc/packages/browser/dart.js
GET http://dartorium.loc/packages/dartorium/nav_menu.dart
An error occurred loading file: package:dartorium/nav_menu.dart
GET http://dartorium.loc/packages/route_hierarchical/client.dart
An error occurred loading file: package:route_hierarchical/client.dart
GET http://dartorium.loc/packages/dartorium/reverser.dart
An error occurred loading file: package:dartorium/reverser.dart
```

This is the pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: 'dartorium'
version: 0.0.1
description: >
  A minimal web app for the developer that doesn’t want to be confused by too
  much going on.
#author: <your name> <email@example.com>
#homepage: https://www.example.com
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  browser: any
  sass: '>=0.4.0 <0.5.0'
  script_inliner: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
  route_hierarchical: '>=0.5.0 <0.7.0'
transformers:
- script_inliner
#- sass:
#    style: compressed
```

This is the log from installing the template the PHPStorm produced:

```
Working dir: /Volumes/Data/htdocs/dartorium
/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec/bin/pub get
Resolving dependencies...
+ analyzer 0.22.4 (0.24.0 available)
+ args 0.12.2+6
+ barback 0.15.2+4
+ browser 0.10.0+2
+ cli_util 0.0.1+1
+ code_transformers 0.2.5
+ collection 1.1.0
+ csslib 0.11.0+4
+ html5lib 0.12.0
+ logging 0.9.3
+ path 1.3.3
+ pool 1.0.1
+ route_hierarchical 0.6.1+1
+ sass 0.4.2
+ script_inliner 1.0.0
+ source_maps 0.10.0+1
+ source_span 1.0.3
+ stack_trace 1.2.1
+ utf 0.9.0+2
+ watcher 0.9.4
+ when 0.2.0
+ which 0.1.3
Changed 22 dependencies!
Precompiling dependencies...
Loading source assets...
Loading script_inliner transformers...
Precompiled script_inliner.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

A directory snapshot

[image]

My vhosts entry just in case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dartorium.loc
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Data/htdocs/dartorium/web"
  <directory /Volumes/Data/htdocs/dartorium>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
    Require all granted
  </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

### Update

I decided to try creating the app outside of PHPStorm. I deleted the app and did 'stagehand webapp' in Terminal to install it again and then 'pub get'. I still got the same errors.

I then noticed a comment in the output that said to do 'pub serve' and then connect to the site on localhost:8080. When I did that, the app ran fine. So now my question is how do you run the app using Apache?

### Answer

The accepted answer below given by Günter Zöchbauer solved the problem. In addition to what is described there, I made two other changes. After any change in the code, I run 'pub build'. I'm spoiled by working in PHP and RoR using RubyMine where all I have to do is refresh the browser. The other change was to my vhosts entry. It's now set to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dartorium.loc
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Data/htdocs/dartorium/build/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

I had originally added the permissions to fix some access problems I had before starting this post. It turns out they weren't necessary. The entry now points to build/web instead of the web directory in which you work.

Comment: Check if the file `dartorium/lib/reverser.dart` exists.

Comment: Does the packages directory contain 'dartorium'?

Comment: Looks all fine. Can you please try to delete the `.pub` directory (1st entry in your screenshot) and try again.

Comment: I deleted the directory and did a shift click reload on the page. No change. In addition, the following error has started popping up: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.dart: "http://dartorium.loc/main.dart".

Comment: It seems PHPStorm 8 doesn't launch 'pub serve' automatically, like WebStorm 9 and 10 do. `pub serve` executes transformers which are needed by some packages. See my answer for your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `pub build` to generate JavaScript output (in build/web). This build output can be served by apache.

The build output works fine in Chrome without change. To make it work in Dartium I changed the script tags:

```dart
<script src="main.dart.js"></script>
<!--<script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script> -->
<!--<script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>-->
```

Comment: Well that was progress. Now I only get the error: GET http://dartorium.loc/main.dart. It's not surprising as build/web has main.dart.js in it. I added my vhosts entry to my original question.

Comment: I tried changing /build/web/index.html to point to main.dart.js instead of main.dart. It crashed Chromium.

Comment: I think this error is normal, the page should work as intended anyway. I think this transformer https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_to_js_script_rewriter fixes the build output to get rid of this message, never tried it myself though.

Comment: Can you make the source available in a GitHub repo?

Comment: No the dart code doesn't run. The browser does render the page. The code is untouched from Stagehand. I have a github account, but I'm going to have to research creating a repo.

Comment: OK, it's at: https://github.com/gcortes/webapp. It's the first time I've done it so it may not be want you want. I had to change .gitignore to get the build to go up.

Comment: I created the `ubersimplewebapp` using stagehand, run `pub get`, then `pub build` and opened the file in Chrome (no script tag change) and it showed 'Your Dart app is running'. I updated my answer.

Comment: Your build output runs fine here in Chrome and Dartium with and without script change using a file URL or a web server. What Dart version are you using? 'dart --version' on the command line or `chrome://version` in Dartium (the "Dart: ... " line)

Comment: The ubersimplewebapp always worked for me even without the pub build. Before I made that change you suggested, I was able to run the app in Firefox without issue. I then made the change, ran pub build, and attempted to run it in Chromium. I got the same error.

Comment: My bad. I changed the code in build/web/index.html and then ran build, which set it back to the original. When I changed it in web, it worked fine.

Comment: dart --version => Dart VM version: 1.8.5 (Tue Jan 13 13:05:45 2015) on "macos_x64"